# Typoscript combine header and subheader of content element header

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want the following result with the TYPO3 content element "header":

```
<header>
    <figure><img src="image.png" alt="Page Title"></figure>
    <div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <h2>Subheader</h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

With the following typoscript i get the most of it, but i have a problem on wrapping the h tags

```
## Wrap header with <header>
lib.stdheader.stdWrap.dataWrap.override = <header class="header-n{cObj:parentRecordNumber}">|</header>

## Header set with image
lib.stdheader.10.11 = COA
lib.stdheader.10.11 {
  1 = IMAGE
  1 {
    file {
        import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.listNum = 0
    }
    altText = TEXT
    altText.data =  page : title
    titleText = TEXT
    titleText.data =  page : title

    wrap = <figure>|</figure>
  }
  2 < lib.stdheader.10.1
}
```

But sadly the result is just:

```
<header class="header-n1">
    <figure><img src="image.png" width="1112" height="546" alt="Pagetitle"></figure>
    <h1 class="csc-firstHeader">Header</h1>
    <h2>Subheader</h2>
</header>
```

Whats the magic to get h1 & h2 wrapped?

if i do it like that

```
2 = COA
2 {
  1 < lib.stdheader.10.1
  2 < lib.stdheader.10.2
  wrap = <div>|</div>
 }
```

the header text is just doubled like

```
<header class="header-n1">
    <figure><img src="image.png" width="1112" height="546" alt="Pagetitle"></figure>
    <div>
        <h1 class="csc-firstHeader">Header</h1>
        <h2 class="csc-firstHeader">Header</h2>
    </div>
    <h2>Subheader</h2>
</header>
```

I´m using TYPO3 6.2

Answer (score 0):

`lib.stdheader.10.*` are actually within a case statement, so only one of them will be taken.
You can do something like that:

```
lib.stdheader.stdWrap.dataWrap.override = <header class="header-n{cObj:parentRecordNumber}">|</header>

lib.stdheader.10.11 = COA
lib.stdheader.10.11 {
  1 = IMAGE
  1 {
    file {
        import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.listNum = 0
    }
    altText = TEXT
    altText.data =  page : title
    titleText = TEXT
    titleText.data =  page : title

    wrap = <figure>|</figure>
  }
  2 = COA 
  2 {
    wrap = <div>|</div>
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      data =  page : title
      wrap = <h1>|</h1>
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
      data = page:subtitle
      wrap = <h2>|</h2>
    } 
  }
}
```

Mind you, the original header functionality (like links etc.) is not being used anymore. You'll have to add it yourself if you need it.

Comment: In your example you take the page subtitle and page title as h1 and h1 of the header content element. 

But what i try to reach is to get the header and the subheader of the header content element and combine it.